# SELECT COUNT(*) returns no data SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, c#

I have a query, that as far as I know has failed exactly one time. It's a simple select count(*) from one table, no joins. But at least this once, executing that query resulted in no data read from SqlDataReader. Not even null, just nothing. First call to Read returns false. No exception was raised.

Has any one ever heard of that before? Any scenarios you can think of that would cause it?

I'm not even sure what to ask for to look at beyond SQL server logs. It's not something we can duplicate. I am assuming I'll have to chalk it up to a fluke and move on if/until it becomes a chronic problem. Here's a similar query:

```
SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(*),0)
FROM dbo.TRANSACTIONS T
WHERE (@TransactionId IS NULL OR (T.TransactionId != @TransactionId))
AND T.ParentId = @ParentId
AND (T.TransactionStatus != 4)
```

Is there a class of error that will thrown an exception out of the query, but not raise it to the application when executing a command or reading from the resulting SqlDataReader?

UPDATE: Here's the code executing this.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = /*connection created and opened here*/)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetChildTransactions");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@transactionId", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = transactionId > 0 ? transactionId : (object)DBNull.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@parentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = parentId;

    using (SqlDataReader rdr = conn.ExecuteReader(cmd))
    {
        rdr.Read();
        itemCount = rdr.IsDBNull(0) ? 0 : rdr.GetInt32(0); //exception thrown here because there is no data
    }
}
```

Update 2: I was hoping to not do this, but maybe the exception handling is part of the problem. Here is the create procedure for this, and also another stored procedure being called in the exception handler. Sorry for the length:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_GetChildTransactions (
    @transactionId              bigint,
    @parentId                   int,
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON 


BEGIN TRY

    SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(*),0)
    FROM dbo.TRANSACTIONS T
    WHERE (@TransactionId IS NULL OR (T.TransactionId != @TransactionId))
    AND T.ParentId = @ParentId
    AND (T.TransactionStatus != 4)

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
    EXEC usp_RethrowException
END CATCH 



CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_RethrowException
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON 

DECLARE @ErrorMessage    NVARCHAR(4000),
       @ErrorNumber     INT,
       @ErrorSeverity   INT,
       @ErrorState      INT,
       @ErrorLine       INT,
       @ErrorProcedure  NVARCHAR(200)

SELECT @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),
       @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
       @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
       @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE(),
       @ErrorProcedure = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-')

if (@ErrorState = 0) set @ErrorState = 1


SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()

IF (LEFT(@ErrorMessage, 15) = N'( Error Number=')
BEGIN

    RAISERROR 
          (@ErrorMessage,
           @ErrorSeverity,
           @ErrorState)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- First time - Create the message with all error information in a standard string format
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = N'( Error Number=%d, Severity=%d, State=%d, Procedure=%s, Line=%d )' + CHAR(13) + @ErrorMessage
    RAISERROR 
          (@ErrorMessage,
           @ErrorSeverity,
           @ErrorState,
           @ErrorNumber,
           @ErrorSeverity,      
           @ErrorState,
           @ErrorProcedure,
           @ErrorLine)
END
```

P.S. I did edit this a little, changing names of the procedures, the name of the table only, and removed comments only.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's pretty hard to tell if there are any errors that might not be caught.

Comment: One thing I can tell you *for certain*, SQL Server will never ever return no result set, if rows exist in the table that match the `WHERE` clause requirements..

Comment: This is a scalar aggregate - it should always return exactly one row even if the source table was empty. `COUNT(*)` can never be `NULL` by the way so the `ISNULL` is pointless. You say " Here's a similar query" does the actual query have any `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Also very unlikely but does your code make use of `set parseonly on` or `noexec` or similar?

Comment: Yeah I didn't add that ISNULL, but it's in the real query so I put it here. i'm not sure why someone would have done that. It made me wonder if this has happened before, and this was someone's misguided attempt at fixing it..

Comment: No set parseonly on or noexec. This is in a stored procedure, only option is set nocount on.

Comment: Any possibility that `usp_GetChildTransactions` can exist in more than one schema? Also have you checked the procedure `modify_date` to rule out it's definition being changed?

Comment: Why, why, why do you need `BEGIN TRY` around a `SELECT COUNT` query? Can you try simplifying the procedure by commenting out all the unnecessary error handling?

Comment: Now you've posted your error handling what is the point of it? If you didn't bother with the try ... catch SQL Server would return all that information for you anyway without possible edge cases such as not being able to raise high severity errors.

Comment: @MartinSmith and Aaron Bertrand I wonder the same thing. I can only assume it's because all of our stored procedures have that, and so they decided to be consistent? I assume the purpose of the Rethrow is to provide a consistent formatting of the error message. In this particular use, I agree it could be removed. We are not relying on a particular message format or anything. However, is that just a criticism of the code or do you think it has something to do with my issue?

Comment: @MartinSmith Missed your earlier comment. No other schema. I don't have access to the live database, so I can't be sure when the stored procedure last changed. As far as source control is concerned it hasn't changed in about a year.

Comment: RE: "do you think it has something to do with my issue" - If an error was being buried there then it could be but I can't see how that would happen.

Comment: @MartinSmith If it is possible the silly RethrowException procedure is losing error severity details, that would be good to know as like I said it's used all over the place. Is calling ERROR_SEVERITY() from a procedure in a CATCH block risky? Seems like it might be better to get those values right inside the catch block, and pass them as parameters to the Rethrow stored proc if formatting the message that way is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a class of error that will thrown an exception out of the
>   query, but not raise it to the application when executing a command or
>   reading from the resulting SqlDataReader?

If the query errs in the scope of T-SQL structured error handling, the empty or partial result set is returned to the client followed by the error message in the TDS protocol stream. The implications are that client code should not assume SqlDataReader always returns true and that all rows and result sets must be consumed before the exception is raised in the client code. Consider the following example:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_ExampleError
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY

    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (VALUES('NotAnInteger')) AS Example(BadData)
    WHERE BadData = 0;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
    THROW;
END CATCH 
GO


using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_ExampleError", connection))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.Read()); //returns false
        Console.WriteLine(reader.NextResult()); //raises the conversion error
    }
}
```

Note that `ExecuteNonQuery` implicitly reads and ignores all rows and result sets (which will raise an exception if the batch erred) but `ExecuteScaler` and `ExecuteReader` do not. Also, `DataAdaper.Fill` consumes all results with a `DataSet` target overload but not with the `DataTable` overload,

This is one reason I suggest one generally avoid handling errors in T-SQL unless it provides value and specify `SET XACT_ABORT ON` to avoid continuing after errors and leaving transactions open.